# Why does my code not enter this adapter class?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to Kotlin and Android studio.
I'm trying to get a recycle view to work properly but I'm running into a problem when trying to use an adapter class.

I tried taking a look with breakpoints. but it seems to trigger on the very first line where the class gets defined. ( so class OrganisationsAdapter...etc ) and after that it skips the whole class, it doesnt even enter it.

I also don't get any exceptions.

**Adapter Class**

```
class OrganisationsAdapter(
    private val myDataset: Array<String>
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<OrganisationsAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {
    
    class MyViewHolder(
        val textView: TextView
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(textView) {
        
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        var cell = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false)
        val textView = cell.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.organisation_name)
        return MyViewHolder(textView)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.textView.text = myDataset[position]
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = myDataset.size
}
```

**The line I use to call the class **

```
recyclerViewOrganisationFragment.adapter = OrganisationsAdapter(Array(getTopics().size) { i -> getTopics()[i].name })
```

Comment: You need to pass on ArrayList on the constructor of the adapter, you are passing a size

Comment: Did you attach layout manager to RecyclerView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you Lakhwinder.

"You need to pass on ArrayList on the constructor of the adapter, you are passing a size"

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the inflated layout to ViewHolder instead of TextView

ex:

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
    var cell = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.example_item, parent, false)
 
    return MyViewHolder(cell)
}


class MyViewHolder(
    val itemView: View
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    //TODO get textview here itemView.findViewByID
}
```

Update the viewholder accordingly with textview etc.,